# how can we Change the container size when the user press on it to add quantity and when the container loses its focus then decrease the container size

Tags: flutter

i want to change the container size when the user presses on it in order to add quantity for the item and then when the user scroll down or up or change the focus of the container then the container will directly change its size in flutter ? How can we implement it ?

Comment: The AnimatedContainer widget can help you to achieve that action, you can animate all the layout properties of this widget, here the link with detail information: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html

Comment: yes i tried animated container it worked for me, but it didn't change it size back when the container loses its focus

Answer (score 0):

Here is the principle:

```
bool isBig=true;

void changeSize (){
// your logic about changing size 
}


Container (height: isBig ? 0 : 156)
```